# Filter treeview from combo-box selected item

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

The tree-view is loaded with some data from a DB. I want to filter tree-view for the selected combo-box item. Anybody show me how to perform this?

```
 public SelectorDataTreeView()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();

            button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

            comboBox1.Items.Add("HP");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("DELL");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Cam");

        }






        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           String s = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
           ExpandAll(MyTreeView.Nodes);
        }




        //TreeKey Finder
        private TreeNode[] FindNode(String searchKey)
        {

            return MyTreeView.Nodes.Find(searchKey, true);

        }
}
```

Comment: do you want to filter treeview or expand a part of it? what is your purpose by filter?

Comment: @ mahdi tahsildari: I want to filter tree-view for the selected combo-box item. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Add("LaptopsNodeKey", "Laptop");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add("CellPhonesNodeKey", "Phones");
        treeView1.Nodes.Find("LaptopsNodeKey", true)[0].Nodes.Add("DellTM", "Dell");
        treeView1.Nodes.Find("LaptopsNodeKey", true)[0].Nodes.Add("SonyTM", "Sony");
        treeView1.Nodes.Find("CellPhonesNodeKey", true)[0].Nodes.Add("HTCTM", "HTC");
        treeView1.Nodes.Find("CellPhonesNodeKey", true)[0].Nodes.Add("NokiaTM", "Nokia");

        comboBox1.Items.Add("LaptopsNodeKey");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("CellPhonesNodeKey");

        comboBox2.Items.Add("Laptop");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Phones");
    }

    //This works because you Loaded ComboBox1 with Name property of Nodes
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.CollapseAll();
        treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find(comboBox1.Text, true)[0];
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Expand();
    }

    //This doesn't work, because you Loaded ComboBox2 with Text property of Nodes
    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.CollapseAll();
        treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find(comboBox1.Text, true)[0];
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Expand();
    }
```

Comment: Excellent but in my treeview the data are loaded from a database. So, I want to look for a group of particular item in the treeview.

Comment: No problem, you can switch `ComboBox1.text` with `ComboBox1.SelectedValue` if you Put appropriate Name for your Nodes, and if you want to Load more than one Node you do that by a simple Foreach loop, But also consider that you can only select one item at a time in a ComboBox, if you need multiselect you'd better use ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, this is your fault:
`String s = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();`
you should use this:
    `String s = comboBox1.Text`;
It's working.
and also you should search for node `Name` property not `Text` property.
after you got `s` you need to use it like
`treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find("WantedNodesName", true)[0];   treeView1.SelectedNode.Expand();`

Comment: you fetch `s` but you don't use it

Comment: Could you give more explanation, possible with the code. I'm having trouble in understanding the search key tree method.

Comment: OK. The search method is based on the `Name` property of the node, for example you may have a tree that has a "Laptops" node, and under this node you have a node with the `Name` : "Dell" and `Text` : "Dell Company Laptops", if you search "Dell Company Laptops" you won't get answer, but if you search "Dell" it works. Am I clear?

Comment: @ mahdi tahsildari:Yes, you are correct. Could you explain to me pro grammatically.

Comment: @linguini I changed my first answer, take a look at it.